# What is the real time benefits of creating Thread in Java?

Tags: java

```
class ThreadDemo extends Thread
{  
    public void run()
    {   
        for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }  

}
class ThreadApp
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        ThreadDemo thread1 =  new ThreadDemo();  
        thread1.start();  
        ThreadDemo thread2 =  new ThreadDemo();  
        thread2.start();  
        ThreadDemo thread3 =  new ThreadDemo();  
        thread3.start();  
    }  
}
```

Output:

```
0
2
3
1
4

1
2
4
3
0

0
1
2
3
4
```

By default, Java applications are single thread application. We are going for the concept called multithreading to share the work. Means, instead of doing the work with one thread (Main thread) if we create the thread, then it will simplifies the work. I understood this thing theoretically. My doubt arises when I start coding.
In the above program I have created 3 threads. If 3 threads are working on the same logic (iteration and printing the values by using for loop) why it is giving 3 separate output instead of giving one set of values from 0 to 4?

Comment: No actually. I understood all the steps to about the creation of threads. My doubt is Why it is not creating a single set of values from (0 to 4) .Instead ,since 3 threads are created, it is giving 3 set of values.

Comment: Oh sorry for that. You passed the same runnable to all the threads. But the runnable doesn't care if it is also getting executed on an other thread, so it just runs every action on every thread. This causes your duplicate results.

Comment: Yes i got it .Thanks

Comment: I suggest to create a program only consisting of the statement `Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().forEach(System.out::println);` and run it, then, rethink your statement “by default, Java applications are single thread application”…

Answer (score 2):

## Duplicating the work, not sharing the work

You said:

> We are going for the concept called multithreading to share the work.

But you did not share the work. You *repeated* the work. Instead of running a `for` loop once, you ran a `for` loop three times, once in each of three threads.

You asked:

> why it is giving 3 separate output instead of giving one set of values from 0 to 4?

If a school teacher asks each of three pupils to write the alphabet on the board, we would end up not with 26 letters but with 78 letters (3 * 26).  Each pupil would be looping through the letters of the alphabet. Likewise, each of your three threads looped through the count of zero to four.

Your `for` loop is local to (within) your task code. So each thread runs all of that code starting at the top. So the `for` loop executes three times, one per thread.

## Beware: `System.out` prints out-of-order

Sending text to `System.out` via calls to `println` or `print` does *not* result in text appearing immediately and in the order sent. The lines of text you send may appear out of order.

When examining a sequence of statements, always include a timestamp such as `java.time.Instant.now()`. Then study the output. You may need to manually re-order the outputs using a text editor to see the true sequence.

You can see the out-of-chronological-order lines in my own example output below.

## Executor service

In modern Java we no longer need address the `Thread` class directly. Generally best to use the Executors framework. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Counter
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Runnable task = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ( )
            {
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
                {
                    System.out.println( "i = " + i + " at " + Instant.now() + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() );
                }
            }
        };
        executorService.submit( task );
        executorService.submit( task );
        executorService.submit( task );

        // Let our program run a while, then gracefully shutdown the executor service.
        // Otherwise the backing thread pool may run indefinitely, like a zombie ‍.
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ).toMillis() ); }catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        executorService.shutdown();
        try { executorService.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

When run.

```
i = 0 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.349290Z on thread pool-1-thread-1
i = 1 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.391997Z on thread pool-1-thread-1
i = 0 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.349246Z on thread pool-1-thread-2
i = 0 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.349464Z on thread pool-1-thread-3
i = 1 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.392467Z on thread pool-1-thread-3
i = 2 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.392162Z on thread pool-1-thread-1
i = 2 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.392578Z on thread pool-1-thread-3
i = 3 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.392670Z on thread pool-1-thread-1
i = 3 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.392773Z on thread pool-1-thread-3
i = 4 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.393165Z on thread pool-1-thread-3
i = 1 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.392734Z on thread pool-1-thread-2
i = 4 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.392971Z on thread pool-1-thread-1
i = 2 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.395138Z on thread pool-1-thread-2
i = 3 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.396407Z on thread pool-1-thread-2
i = 4 at 2021-01-06T05:28:34.397002Z on thread pool-1-thread-2
```

## Project Loom

Project Loom promises to be bring to Java new features such as virtual threads (fibers), and making `ExecutorService` be `AutoCloseable` for use with try-with-resources to automatically shutdown.

Let's rewrite the above code to use Project Loom technologies. Preliminary builds are available now based on early-access Java 16.

Also, we can rewrite the anonymous class seen above with simpler lambda syntax.

Another difference from above: Virtual threads do not have a name. So we switch to using the id number of the thread to differentiate between threads running.

```java
try
        (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
        )
{
    Runnable task = ( ) -> {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( "i = " + i + " at " + Instant.now() + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() );
        }
    };
    executorService.submit( task );
    executorService.submit( task );
    executorService.submit( task );
}
// At this point, the flow-of-control blocks until all submitted tasks are done.
// And the executor service is also shutdown by this point.
```

When run.

```
i = 0 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.628800Z on thread 17
i = 1 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.647428Z on thread 17
i = 2 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.647626Z on thread 17
i = 3 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.647828Z on thread 17
i = 4 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.647902Z on thread 17
i = 0 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.628842Z on thread 14
i = 1 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.648148Z on thread 14
i = 2 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.648227Z on thread 14
i = 3 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.648294Z on thread 14
i = 4 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.648365Z on thread 14
i = 0 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.628837Z on thread 16
i = 1 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.648839Z on thread 16
i = 2 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.648919Z on thread 16
i = 3 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.648991Z on thread 16
i = 4 at 2021-01-06T05:41:36.649054Z on thread 16
```

## Sharing state across threads

If you really wanted to share values across the threads, you define them outside the immediate task code.

In this next example, we define a class `Counter` that implements `Runnable`. As a `Runnable` we can pass an instance of this class to an executor service. We defined a member field, a `ConcurrentMap` (a thread-safe `Map`) that tracks each of our desired numbers 0-4. For each of those five numbers, we map to the id number of the virtual thread that was able to beat the other virtual threads to submitting that entry into our originally-empty map.

Be aware that we are submitting a single `Counter` object to all three threads. So all three threads have access to the very same `ConcurrentMap` object. That is why we must use a `ConcurrentMap` rather than a plain `Map`. Any resource shared across threads must be built to be thread-safe.

We are calling `Thread.sleep` to try to mix things up. Otherwise, the first thread might finish all the work while the main thread is still submitting to the second and third threads.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Counter implements Runnable
{
    public ConcurrentMap < Integer, Long > results = new ConcurrentHashMap <>();

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( 100 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        Long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();  // ID of this thread.
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
        {
            // Shake things up by waiting some random time.
            try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 100) ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            results.putIfAbsent( i , threadId );  // Auto-boxing converts the `int` value of `i` to be wrapped as a `Integer` object.
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a `main` method to make our exercise happen.

```java
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        try
                (
                        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
                )
        {
            executorService.submit( counter );
            executorService.submit( counter );
            executorService.submit( counter );
        }
        // At this point, the flow-of-control blocks until all submitted tasks are done.
        // And the executor service is also shutdown by this point.
        System.out.println( "counter.results = " + counter.results );
    }
```

In the results of this particular run, we can see that the two threads number 16 and 17 had all the success in putting entries into our map. The third thread was not able to be the first to put in any of the five entries.

> counter.results = {0=16, 1=17, 2=17, 3=16, 4=16}

Answer (score 1):

Try to do some various tests and see by yourself what is coming and from where

```
public class ThreadApp {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadDemo thread1 = new ThreadApp().new ThreadDemo("t1",4);
        ThreadDemo thread2 = new ThreadApp().new ThreadDemo("t2",7);
        thread2.start();
        thread1.start();

        ThreadDemo thread3 = new ThreadApp().new ThreadDemo("t3",2);
        // wait till t1 &t2 finish run then launch t3
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
        thread3.start();
    }

    class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
        int stop;
        public ThreadDemo(String name, int stop) {
            super(name);
            this.stop = stop;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
                System.out.println(this.getName() + ":" + i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Possible Output:

```
t2:0
t2:1
t1:0
t2:2
t1:1
t2:3
t1:2
t2:4
t1:3
t2:5
t2:6
//due to join t3 start only after t1 & t2 finish their run
t3:0
t3:1
```

Related to benefits, just one hint `Producer-Consumer` problem ...